# Finding the parametric equation for a longbow curve about a circle

Tags: parametric

In the figure the circle of radius $a$ is stationary, and for every $\theta$, the point $P$ is the midpoint of the segment $QR$. The curve traced out by $P$ for $0<\theta<\pi$ is called *the longbow curve*. Find the parametric equations for this curve.

[image]

Comment: So where are you stuck at? What did you do so far?

Comment: Like flawr said. Once you show what you've tried we'll be glad to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The obvious choice as a parameter is $\theta$ as both $Q$ and $R$ depend on $\theta$.  Try to express $R$ and $Q$ as functions of $\theta$, then notice that $P = \frac 1 2 (Q+R)$.

If you do not succeed, I suggest looking at the article [Witch of Agnesi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch_of_Agnesi).